# Router resolve will not inject into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-service

I have tried everything to get ui-router's resolve to pass it's value to the given controller–AppCtrl. I am using dependency injection with `$inject`, and that seems to cause the issues. What am I missing?

**Routing**

```
$stateProvider.state('app.index', {
  url: '/me',
  templateUrl: '/includes/app/me.jade',
  controller: 'AppCtrl',
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  resolve: {
    auser: ['User', function(User) {
      return User.getUser().then(function(user) {
        return user;
      });
    }],
  }
});
```

**Controller**

```
appControllers.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

AppCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope'];

function AppCtrl($scope, $rootScope, auser) {
  var vm = this;
  console.log(auser); // undefined

  ...
}
```

**Edit**
Here's a plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/PoCiEnh64hR4XM24aH33?p=preview

Comment: Did you miss injecting `auser` ? `AppCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'auser'];`

Comment: injecting `auser` results in a `[$injector:unpr]` error. :(

Comment: You cannot provide ng-controller You need to set it up with route only

Comment: Great input! It works :D You want to post as an answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use route resolve argument as dependency injection in the controller bound to the route,  you cannot use that controller with ng-controller directive because the service provider with the name `aname` does not exist. It is a dynamic dependency that is injected by the router when it instantiates the controller to be bound in its respective partial view.

Also remember to return `$timeout` in your example, because it returns a promise otherwise your argument will get resolved with no value, same is the case if you are using `$http` or another service that returns a promise.

i.e

```
  resolve: {
    auser: ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
      return $timeout(function() {
        return {name:'me'}
      }, 1000);
    }],
```

In the controller inject the resolve dependency.

```
appControllers.controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

AppCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope','auser']; //Inject auser here

function AppCtrl($scope, $rootScope, auser) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.user = auser;
}
```

in the view instead of ng-controller, use `ui-view` directive:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3Ol547mzzXxz5IcEc1ed?p=preview)**

Comment: This comment "//Inject auser here" just solved my 2 hours research!! Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I work with resolve. It should receive promise. So I create service accordingly.

```
app.factory('User', function($http){
    var user = {};
    return {
        resolve: function() {
            return $http.get('api/user/1').success(function(data){
                user = data;
            });
        },
        get: function() {
            return user;
        }
    }
});
```

This is main idea. You can also do something like this with `$q`

```
app.factory('User', function($q, $http){
    var user = {};
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http.get('api/user/1').success(function(data){
        user = data;
        defer.resolve();
    }).error(function(){
        defer.reject();
    });

    return {
        resolve: function() {
            return defer.promise;
        },
        get: function() {
            return user;
        }
    }
});
```

These are almost identical in action. The difference is that in first case, service will start fetching date when you call `resolve()` method of service and in second example it will start fetch when factory object is created.

Now in your state.

```
$stateProvider.state('app.index', {
  url: '/me',
  templateUrl: '/includes/app/me.jade',
  controller: function ($scope, $rootScope, User) {
    $scope.user = User.get();
    console.log($scope.user);
  },
  controllerAs: 'vm',
  resolve: {
    auser: function(User) {
      return User.resolve()
    }
  }
});
```