# Resolve objects not available in $injector

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, route-provider

I have a route definition as follows:

```
.state('user_login', {
                url: '/user/login',
                templateUrl: 'login.tpl.html',
                controller: 'AuthenticationCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    practice: ['$q', function($q) {
                        return $q.when({});
                    }]
                }
            })
```

Things work as expected when I inject "practice" into the controller. When I use the $injector, service however:

`$injector.get('practice')`

I get an unknown provider exception. Are resolve objects not available to the $injector? How I can expose them in the controller without explicitly injecting them in the controller definition?

Note: I am using Angular 1.2.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot get them separately via `$injector`. And [you *cannot* even inject them separately as well in other places, say the same controller (`AuthenticationCtrl`) instantiated by `ng-controller` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914436/router-resolve-will-not-inject-into-controller/27914669#27914669).

Resolve objects are not any service or any other entity which can be injected separately. It is a special dependency injected by the router when the controller `AuthenticationCtrl` is bound via the router. You cannot get the instances separately. Only router knows about the resolve properties and while the router instantiates the controller (*once all the resolve dependencies are resolved*) it looks for resolve properties in the annotation (of the dependency list specified via explicit/implicit dependency annotation in the definision of `AuthenticationCtrl`) of the route-bound controller and injects them as required.

This kind of special implementation can be found in other components as well like, angular-ui-modal, ui-state-router, angular-router's routeprovider etc..