# resolve not running before entering route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

[this is a jsbin showing the problem](http://jsbin.com/mavoxo/1/edit?html,js,output), however, I will explain it here. I am trying to use `resolve` to run some code before entering a route, however, it doesn't run (as the console.log statement provides more detail about). (Since it doesn't run, I'm not sure if I'm setting what would be the return value from `resolve` in the template correctly).  Why isn't `resolve` running?

```
var app = angular.module('jsbin', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        'use strict';
        console.log("this runs");

        var routeConfig = {
            controller: 'DemoCtrll',
            resolve: {
                store: function (demoStorage) {
                console.log("this doesn't log");
                    return demoStorage;
                }
            }
        };

        $routeProvider
            .when('/', routeConfig)
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
});

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, store) { 
  this.name = store;
});

app.factory('demoStorage', function () {
        'use strict';
        return "World";
});
```

html

```
<body ng-app="jsbin">
  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as demo">
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some changes you would need:

- You cannot use `ng-controller` directive along with ng-view's route bound controller, i.e set controller alias in the controller property of the route config `controller: 'DemoCtrl as demo',`.
- When you use ng-controller directive to instantiate the controller it does not know what is `store` provider, because no such provider/service exists. It is a special dependency injected by the angular router and only the router knows how to inject `store` as dependency in your controller. That is the reason for the error when you used `ng-controller`.
- You need to define a template html or a template and bind it to `templateUrl` property on the routeConfig. i.e `templateUrl:'demo.html',`
- Remove `ng-controller` from the view.
- You need to use `ng-view` directive to render the view. i.e in your index.html `<ng-view></ng-view>`
- Since you are using controller alias you would refer to the property as `demo.name` in the view rendered by the route.
- You also had a typo in the controller name @`DemoCtrl1`.

Overall it will look like this.

Define your template in say `Demo.html` (In the demo example i have used the convenient script `type="text/ng-template"`)

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello {{demo.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

Set the routeConfig:

```
  var routeConfig = {
      templateUrl:'demo.html',
        controller: 'DemoCtrl as demo',
        resolve: {
            store: function (demoStorage) {
                console.log("this doesn't log");
                return demoStorage;
            }
        }
    };
```

**[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/gufozuhete/2/)**

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914436/router-resolve-will-not-inject-into-controller/27914669#27914669) though it uses angular ui-router, but the concept is the same.

Comment: so is it an either/or with where you declare the controller? Could it be in the html if I didn't declare it in the routeConfig?

Comment: @Leahcim Sure, you could intialize it with ng-controller provided you do not inject the resolve dependency. resolve dependency is a special dependency injected by angular router when it instantiates the controller. But better practice is to instantiate the main controller with the router. It let you get your partial view more reusable.